# Google Analytics - Acquisition Channel & Cost for each Transaction ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm currently stuck trying to create a report that shows me cost data and acquisition channel on a transaction id basis. For each individual transaction id, I'd like to know:
1) what was the acquisition channel?
2) how much did it cost me? (AdWords and imported FB ad spend data)

Is it possible to set up this report in GA? If not, can you recommend another tool to use for this? Any help is highly appreciated :)

Cheers, 
Anna

Answer (score 0):

GA has a report Acquisition>Campaigns>Cost Analysis
For Adwords and FB, it would provide you results in Campaigns. Make sure your Adwords and Analytics accounts are linked. 
FB Ads: While Creating FB ad, enter URL tagged with UTM parameters eg http://www.example.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=paid&utm_campaign=testname

Use 'transaction id' as secondary dimension in report or create a custom report.

Hope it helps.